# How to update table on postgres with join statement

Tags: postgresql, join, sql-update

I have three tables on postgresql DB, and tried to update table but I failed to get result what I want. Please help me with getting valid result.

The first table is "employee".
On this table, the first three characters of "employee_id" mean employee type.
For example, employee_id="AA1-11111" is a member of employee_type="AA1".

| employee_id | department |
| --- | --- |
| AA1-11111 | A |
| AA1-22222 | B |
| AB1-11111 | A |

The second table is "assessment".
On this table, assessment criteria is defined for (employee_type, department).
For example, an employee of employee_type="AA1" and department="A" will be evaluated by assessment_criteria="XX1X".

| employee_type | department | assessment_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | A | XX1X |
| AA1 | B | XX1Y |
| AA2 | A | XX2X |

The third table is "employee_assessment". On this table assessment_criteria for each employee is defined. (This table is calculated from "employee" and "assessment" by night batch processing.)

| employee_id | department | assessment_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1-11111 | A | XX1X |
| AA1-22222 | B | XX1Y |
| AB1-11111 | A | Null |

What I want to do is... to update "employee_assessment" table when "assessment" table is updated.
When "assessment" table is updated as like below...

| employee_type | department | assessment_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | A | XX1X |
| AA1 | B | NEW |
| AA2 | A | Null |

I want to update "employee_assessment" table like this.

| employee_id | department | assessment_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1-11111 | A | XX1X |
| AA1-22222 | B | NEW |
| AB1-11111 | A | Null |

I tried

```sql
UPDATE
employee_assessment
SET assessment_criteria=employee_assessment.assessment_criteria
FROM employee
LEFT JOIN (SELECT employee_id, LEFT(employee_id,3) as emp_type, department as emp_department from employee) as t1
ON
employee.employee_id=t1.employee_id
and
employee.department=t1.emp_department
left join assessment
on
t1.emp_type=assessment.employee_type
and
t1.emp_department=assessment.department;
```

But I got this result.

| employee_id | department | assessment_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA1-11111 | A | XX1X |
| AA1-22222 | B | XX1X |
| AB1-11111 | A | XX1X |

My query seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The actual cause of the problem is that you schema isn't properly normalized. Therefore you should solve this by fixing and normalizing your schema. Then you can simply use a view, that is "updated" automatically.

First have tables for the types and departments (unless you have that already (that's unclear)).

```
CREATE TABLE type
             (id serial,
              name varchar(64),
              PRIMARY KEY (id));

CREATE TABLE department
             (id serial,
              name varchar(64),
              PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Then, in the table for the employees, just reference the types and departments. Don't have a column that actually are two columns, i.e. the type id has to have its own column and must not be concatenated to any other.

```
CREATE TABLE employee
             (id serial,
              type integer,
              department integer,
              given_name varchar(64),
              surname varchar(64),
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (type)
                          REFERENCES type
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (department)
                          REFERENCES department
                                     (id));
```

In the table for the assessments reference the types and departments too.

```
CREATE TABLE assessment
             (id serial,
              type integer,
              department integer,
              name varchar(64),
              criteria varchar(64),
              PRIMARY KEY (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (type)
                          REFERENCES type
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (department)
                          REFERENCES department
                                     (id));
```

Now you can create view for the employee assessments that joins the data from the other tables and is always up to date. There's no need for any manual `UPDATE`.

```
CREATE VIEW employee_assessment
AS
SELECT e.id employee_id,
       e.department employee_department,
       a.criteria assessment_criteria
       FROM employee e
            LEFT JOIN assessment a
                      ON a.type = e.type
                         AND a.department = e.department;
```

A view also has the advantage that it cannot contain inconsistent data as the table you have now could.